# написать формулу для y= ln(2)+sum{n=1}{infty}(((-1)^(n-1))*(x^n)/((2^n)*n))

Tags: vba

`S` и `Y` должны совпадать в таблице, а у меня это не выходит. Ошибки вроде как не вижу. Можете помочь найти проблему, ошибку

```
Public Sub Rinda()
    Dim x As Single, a As Single, S As Single, Y As Single, j As Single
    Dim k As Integer, i As Integer

    Cells(1, 1) = "i"        
    Cells(1, 2) = "x"        
    Cells(1, 3) = "S"        
    Cells(1, 4) = "Y"        
    Cells(1, 5) = "k"        

    i = 2       
    x = -1

    Do While (x < 1.01)        
        S = (x / 2) + (x ^ 2 / 8)        
        a = (x ^ 2 / 8)        
        k = 3  

        Do While (Abs(a) > 0.0001)        
            a = -a * (x * (k - 1) / (2 * k))        
            S = S + a        
            k = k + 1        
        Loop  

        Y = Log(2 + x)
        S = Log(2 + S)        
        Cells(i, 1) = i - 1        
        Cells(i, 2) = x        
        Cells(i, 3) = S         
        Cells(i, 4) = Y        
        Cells(i, 5) = k        
        '    MsgBox (x & S & Y & k) '        
        x = x + 0.1        
        i = i + 1        
    Loop        
End Sub
```

Comment: Вы бы переменные называли так же, как в формуле-примере. Или напишите пояснения к коду. Где *х*, где *n*? Почему, например, *x ^ 2 / 8* (такого в формуле нет)? Почему *Log(2 + x)*, если в формуле логарифм стоит отдельно от суммы, получаемой в цикле?

Comment: Каждый последующий элемент находится из предыдущего. Получаем, что первый элемент = -(x/2), второй =(x^2/8). a - предыдущий результат(всегда последний приплюсованный аргумент). Ну а S, то что получается. Алгоритм может работать, только когда 2 первых известны, чтобы продолжить работать по аналогии. k это тот же n. Log(2+x) это то, чему должны быть равны результаты из второго цикла. а вот с Log(2+S) действительно ошибочка, должно быть Log(2)+S.

Comment: Все равно непонятно (судя по количеству ответов, не только мне). Глядя на формулу и на код, вижу только отдаленное сходство.*первый элемент = -(x/2), второй =(x^2/8)*- из чего это следует? Почему Вы задаете k=3?

Comment: Из sum{n=1}{infty}(((-1)^(n-1))*(x^n)/((2^n)*n)) естественно. первый элемент начинается с k=1 (n=1) подставляем n равное одному и получаем первый элемент. Тоже самое со вторым(k естественно увеличиваем на 1). k=3 потому как мы уже ищем 3 элемент.(предыдущие два уже найдены)  a = -a * (x * (k - 1) / (2 * k))   - это то, на что надо умножить предыдущий результат, чтобы получить следующий.

Answer (score 1):

> первый элемент = -(x/2), второй =(x^2/8)

С минусом напутали: первый элемент = *0.5x*, второй = *-0.125x^2*

Попутно: ускоряем, заполняя массив и минимизируя обращение к объектам листа:

```
Sub Rinda()
Dim ar(1 To 22, 1 To 5)
Dim x As Single, a As Single, S As Single, Y As Single, j As Single
Dim k As Integer, i As Integer
    ar(1, 1) = "i": ar(1, 2) = "x"
    ar(1, 3) = "S": ar(1, 4) = "Y": ar(1, 5) = "k"
    i = 2: x = -1

    Do While (x < 1.01)
        a = -0.125 * x ^ 2
        S = 0.5 * x + a
        k = 3

        Do While (Abs(a) > 0.0001)
            a = -a * x * (k - 1) / (2 * k)
            S = S + a
            k = k + 1
        Loop

        Y = Log(2 + x)
        S = Log(2) + S
        ar(i, 1) = i - 1: ar(i, 2) = x
        ar(i, 3) = S: ar(i, 4) = Y: ar(i, 5) = k

        x = x + 0.1: i = i + 1
    Loop

    Cells(1, 1).Resize(22, 5).Value = ar
End Sub
```

Comment: Действительно. Спасибо Вам :)